# Select All rows WHERE ARRAY = "type"

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have a problem with a PostgreSQL query.

I have a table named "pokemons" with different columns :

```sql
 id  |    name    | pv  | attaque | defense | attaque_spe | defense_spe | vitesse |       type       
-----+------------+-----+---------+---------+-------------+-------------+---------+------------------
   1 | Bulbizarre |  45 |      49 |      49 |          65 |          65 |      45 | {Plante,Poison}
   2 | Herbizarre |  60 |      62 |      63 |          80 |          80 |      60 | {Plante,Poison}
   3 | Florizarre |  80 |      82 |      83 |         100 |         100 |      80 | {Plante,Poison}
   4 | Salameche  |  39 |      52 |      43 |          60 |          50 |      65 | {Feu}
   5 | Reptincel  |  58 |      64 |      58 |          80 |          65 |      80 | {Feu}
   6 | Dracaufeu  |  78 |      84 |      78 |         109 |          85 |     100 | {Feu,Vol}
   7 | Carapuce   |  44 |      48 |      65 |          50 |          64 |      43 | {Eau}
   8 | Carabaffe  |  59 |      63 |      80 |          65 |          80 |      58 | {Eau}
   9 | Tortank    |  79 |      83 |     100 |          85 |         105 |      78 | {Eau}
```

In this table, I want to select all the rows with a specific type.

Kind of things, I did try :

```sql
SELECT * FROM pokemons WHERE 'feu'=ANY(type);
```

I tried many things with ALL or stuff like that but can't get a single a row.

Can you help me there please.

Thanks.

Comment: String comparison is case sensitive. You need to use `WHERE 'Feu' = ANY(type)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to the solution mentioned in the comment, you may also make a case insensitive comparison like this.

```
SELECT * FROM pokemons WHERE 'feu' ilike ANY(type);
```